# How to escape triple quotes in C# string for the use GraphQL queries?

Tags: c#, graphql, shopify, .net-4.6.1

I am trying to run a [Shopify bulkOperationRunQuery](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/usage/bulk-operations/queries#step-1-submit-a-query) using [GraphQL.Client](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-client).

The Query field needs to be set to the the below, but I am unable to set the Query field (type string) to include the triple quotes.

As an example, this is what needs to be posted, as shown on Shopify docs:

```
mutation {
  bulkOperationRunQuery(
   query: """
    {
      products {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            title
          }
        }
      }
    }
    """
  ) {
    bulkOperation {
      id
      status
    }
    userErrors {
      field
      message
    }
  }
}
```

This is the code. I've tried using backslashes, and more double quotes in attempt to escape the quotes, but I haven't been successful.

```
var request = new GraphQLRequest
{
    Query = @"""
        mutation {
            bulkOperationRunQuery(
            query 
            """
            {
                products {
                    edges {
                        node {
                        id
                        title
                    }
                }
                }
            }
            """
            ) {
            bulkOperation {
                id
                status
            }
        userErrors
        {
            field
            message
            }
            }
        }
        """
};


var response = await graphQlClient.SendQueryAsync<dynamic>(request);
```

How do I escape the triple quotes to be included in the Query string?

**EDIT:**
This is a .NET 4.6.1 project. I am unable to use C# 11 features.
Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Iirc a quote gets escaped by writing two quotes, so three should be like six?

Comment: @flq Doubling worked. I marked the post with your same suggestion as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside a literal string (preceded with @) you can escape quotations by doubling them.  Keep in mind you still need to have your opening and closing quotations, so if you need a string that starts with 3 quotes, you will have 7 as shown:

```cs
var Query = @"""""""
  mutation {
      bulkOperationRunQuery(
      query 
      """"""
      {
  products {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        title
              }
    }
  }
}
""""""
      ) {
  bulkOperation {
    id
    status
      }
  userErrors
  {
    field
    message
      }
}
}
  """"""";
```

Comment: Doubling the inner quotes to 6 did it for me.  I needed to keep the outer quote as just one single `@" ..."` otherwise the output contained extra leading and trailing quotes. Assuming the discrepancy is my .net / C# version.

Comment: @Rivka that sounds right.  That would mean you have 7 quotes to produce 3 in the string at the very start and very end.  Ones in the middle of the string would only have 6 to produce 3.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of escaping `"""`, start and end your string with four quotes like this:

```cs
var myStringWithTripleQuotes = """" """ """";
```

> You're allowed more than three consecutive characters to start and end the sequence in order to support string literals that contain three (or more) repeated quote characters.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#raw-string-literals

Comment: This is cool. But I am unable to use C# 11 features as this project is using .net 4.6. I updated my OP with this info.

Comment: @Rivka 4.6 went fully end-of-support just over a year ago, meaning it's been over a year since any security patches were available. I know you may not have control here, but you should push to get to at least 4.8, which still gets security patches. 4.6-4.8 is a fairly painless upgrade that shouldn't require any code changes.

Comment: 4.8.1, 4.8 is out of support too.